# HIPI on hadoop1.2.1 exceptions while running hibInfo.sh

Tags: java, hadoop, gradle, hipi

Friends,

I started using hipi on my hadoop1.2.1 multinode cluster(1master, 2 slaves). I have installed gradle, build everything as mentioned in the instructions of virginia.edu getting started.

When I run hibImport.sh with set of images from local disk, they are exported successfully to Hadoop as .hib and .hib.dat files. I can browse them in HDFS

But when I run hibInfo.sh , It is throwing exceptions as below. I tried everything. But nothing worked. what can be the possible problem? Can someone please help me.

```
Input HIB: /inputimages.hib
Display meta data: true
Display EXIF data: false
```

> 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.drew.metadata.Metadata.getDirectories()Ljava/lang/Iterable;' 'at
>   org.hipi.image.io.ExifDataReader.extractAndFlatten(ExifDataReader.java:48)'
>   'at org.hipi.image.io.ImageCodec.decodeImage(ImageCodec.java:118)'

Thanks

Comment: It automatically got resolved once I build again and restarted the PC .. Hope this helps people who are facing same problems...

Comment: I am getting the same error, did you done anything specifically? It is an Eclipse Maven project